# Assign module method to a Class variable or Instance variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, class-variables, class-instance-variables

In module **a.py**

```
def task(): 
    print "task called"

a = task

class A:

    func = task              # this show error unbound method
    #func = task.__call__    # if i replace with this work

    def __init__(self):
        self.func_1 = task

    def test_1(self):
        self.func_1()

    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        cls.func()


a()
A().test_1()
A.test()
```

**Output:**

```
task called
task called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 26, in <module>
     A.test()
  File "a.py", line 21, in test
     cls.func()
TypeError: unbound method task() must be called with A instance as 
first argument (got nothing instead)
```

In the module, I can easily assign a function to a variable. When inside class try to assign module level function to class variable **func = task** it shows error, to remove this error I have to replace it with **func = task.__call__**  But when I assign to instance variable its work **self.func_1 = task**.

My Question is: why I can't assign a module level function to a class variable without  **__call__** and when the same function I can assign to an instance variable is working.

Comment: Additionally, it is worth noting that this compiles and works as expected in python 3.x (specifically 3.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you mapped a function as unbound method of `A`, so when you are calling `cls.func` you first ask something equals to `getattr(cls, 'func')` which returns `<unbound method A.task>` BUT, this unbound method needs to be called with class as first argument.

So because in this specific case `cls.func` means "gives me class attribute `func` of `cls`" it can not means to the same time "call class method `func`" - So Python doesn't translate `cls.func()` by `func(cls)`.

But within the same time, because `func` is `<unbound method A.task>` (bound to `A.task`) it needs to be called like `func(cls)` to work.

Check it with something like:

```
@classmethod
def test(cls):
    print getattr(cls, 'func') # <unbound method A.task>
```

You could fix it with something like:

```
def task(cls=None):
    if cls is None:
        print 'task()'
    else:
        print 'A.foo({})'.format(cls)

a = task

class A:
    func = task             # this show error unbound method

    def __init__(self):
        self.func_1 = task

    def test_1(self):
        self.func_1()

    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        cls.func(cls())

a()
A().test_1()
A.test()
```

Output:

```
task()
task()
A.foo(<__main__.A instance at 0x7fd0310a46c8>)
```

**Note that python3 removes unbound methods, this works only with python2.x**

Comment: what is source for this